# deletion of data based on comparison with current datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a issue while delete the data from table..

I will explain that to you in detail first.

See i have one table with 1000 of records

i have one more table with two columns

```
**circle - Chennai (present in both table)**
**starttime -- 23/5/2013 07:00:00:000**
**endtime -- 23/5/2013 09:00:00:000**
```

This table have data like this...

now the issue is i have to delete the data from first table when currentdatetime is greater than starttime and currentdatetime is less than endtime..that i am doing on the base of CIRCLE which is common in both tables.

If Cicle is same and currenttime coming between both times so i want all records to be deleted of that perticular circle...

i tried with different ways..but nothing works...please guys help me on this...i wll be highly obliged to you...

CurrentDatetime i am taking from GETDATE()....there is no column present in any table for currentdatetime...

I have already tried for this like..

```
DELETE A
FROM TABLEA A join TABLEB B
on A.CIRCLE=B.CIRCLE
WHERE GETDATE() > B.starttime and GETDATE() < B.endtime



 DELETE 
 FROM   S    

 FROM S   t
 INNER JOIN AutoClickDisableTimeline  tm
 ON  t.circle = tm.circle
 WHERE
 GETDATE() between tm.StartTime and tm.EndTime)
```

Here s table comtains 1000 of data...
Autoclickdisabletimeline table contains....

```
circle   starttime              endtime
chennai  23/05/2013 09:00:00:000    23/05/2013 18:00:00:000
```

Comment: What happens when you do that (error, wrong result,...)?

Comment: dude the query above what you are saying as u have tried is not urs and you just took it from my answer.

Comment: yes dear...this is the way i have already tried...thats y i put this query there..

Comment: @Serge wrong results...records r nt getting deleted..

Comment: Don't you have trigger on tableA?

Comment: no..no triger here @Serge

Comment: @Ashu please show us a record that doesn't get deleted + an explanation why it should be deleted.

Comment: go through the quest nw...i have added in that... @Serge

Comment: You do know that 15/03/2013 18:00:00:000 belong to the past, right? Meaning GETDATE() isn't between the 2 dates you provided there.

Comment: Give sample data in http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: @Serge its just an example dude...take a guess of todays date...

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE A
FROM TABLEA A join TABLEB B
on A.CIRCLE=B.CIRCLE
WHERE GETDATE() > B.starttime and GETDATE() < B.endtime
```

Comment: comparison comdition is somewhat different here...there is no column with current datetime....this i have to get using GETDATE()...

Comment: yes dear...i tried with this...but this is not working...please give me some other solution if possible....

Comment: not an error..but i am not getting the expected results..after deletion command if i am fetching records..then also records r coming..that means thosa are not deleting...

Comment: is there any date column in your first table? If not then how are you going to decide on which rows to be deleted?

Comment: i think because we are comparing here with getdate function which is nt a part of any table..its ignoring that condition..tbhats why its not deleting.....where condition should contain columns which are present in used tables...i think so...

Comment: based on circle.....i am comparing the current time with starttime and endtime...if its coming between these both...so i am deleting all rows of that circle data...